# input() is linking one answer with another

Tags: python, input

When I typed A for a response to the following python code

```
def Choice():
    d1 = input(*question*)
    if d1 == 'A':
        print(*response*)

    if d1 == 'B':
        print(*response*)

    else:
        print(*response*)
        Choice()
```

I got the response for A, but I also got the response for the 'else:' statement. However, when I typed B for the response, I got the answer without the response to the 'else:' statement.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: `else` is else to only the `if` before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `elif`

```
def Choice():
    d1 = input(*question*)
    if d1 == 'A':
        print(*response*)

    elif d1 == 'B':
        print(*response*)

    else:
        print(*response*)
        Choice()
```

what happens i your code is if `d1 == 'A'` then it will go to next if then `d1 !='B'` so it will got to else and print statement for 'A' and else condition.

if you use elif, if d1 is not 'A' or 'B' then only it will go to else condition

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using `if else` statements, the else is linked to the **most** recent if statement.
So what is happening in your code is, whenever you are giving 'A' as input, the first if statement is executed, then it checks for another if statement to which the condition stands **false** and the corresponding else is executed.

But that is not the case with input 'B'. if you write one else statement after the first if, the same case will happen, since there is no `else` statement after `if`, it goes to another `if` statement which stands true.

To counter it use can use the `if elif else` concept.

You can follow what Nihal has done.